# Как выделить слово цветом?

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите как выделить слово красным в «div», после нажатия пробела, если оно неправильно введено с input или зеленый, если правильно ?

```
if (e.value == arr[i]){
i++;
document.getElementById('form').reset();
event.preventDefault();
}
```

Эта строчка срабатывает, когда слово вводиться верно и оно пропадает с инпута при этом условии если был нажат пробел, нужно что бы еще слово в диве, после правильного ввода окрашивалось в зеленый цвет и так же при ошибке, слово становилось красным
`arr[i].style.color = 'green';` когда добавлю в условие правильного слова, то не работает

```js
var arr = [];
var i = 0;
window.onload = function () {
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    txt = text.textContent || text.innerText;
    arr = txt.split(' ');
    console.log(arr);
    //alert(txt.substring(0,3));
};
function getChar(e) {

    if (event.which == 32) {
        if (e.value == arr[i]){
            arr[i].style.color = 'green';
  i++;

            document.getElementById('form').reset();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium alias aperiam commodi
    consequatur corporis cum dolores eaque in labore molestias nam odio optio quas, quis voluptates!
    Architecto fuga impedit voluptatum.</div>
<form action="" id="form">
    <input type="text" id="text_input" onkeydown="getChar(this);">
</form>
```

Comment: Завернуть каждое слово в `div`-e в `span`.

Comment: мне кажется, что это не правильно

Comment: Вам кажется неправильно.

Comment: с подсеткой неправильного слова будут проблемы. так как не понятно какое слово подсвечивать... с правильными проблемы нет.. нашел в тексте..обернул. слова с ошибкой, набранные в инпуте надо прогонять на отличие символов и вычислять наиболее подобные.. это сильно усложняет задачу.

Comment: @СергейПетрашко судя по коду, слова сравниваются просто по порядку

Comment: я тут уже блина навоял почти  чуть не подсветку синтаксиса и редактор с блэкджеком...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Подскажите как выделить слово красным в «div», после нажатия пробела, если оно неправильно введено с input или зеленый, если правильно ?
>
> Эта строчка срабатывает, когда слово вводиться верно и оно пропадает с инпута при этом условии если был нажат пробел, нужно что бы еще слово в диве, после правильного ввода окрашивалось в зеленый цвет и так же при ошибке, слово становилось красным

Такой вариант, выделения.

```js
var arr = [];
var i = 0;
window.onload = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  txt = text.textContent || text.innerText;
  arr = txt.split(' ');

};
//----------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Checking spelling
function checkSpelling(fun, where, what) {
  if (fun(where, what)) {
    what.classList.remove('red');
    return true;
  } else { // 
    what.classList.add('red');
    return false;
  }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// One word checker
function oneWord(where, what) {
  return where.textContent.includes(what.value);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// All words checker
function allWords(where, what) {
  let input = what.value.split(' ');
  // We need exact match of the word that is why === 
  return input.every(val => !!where.find(w => w === val));
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Change Text Color
function changeTextColor(where, what, color) {
  var res = Array.from(where); // Clone array
  let input = what.value.split(' ');
  // Run on array
  where.forEach(function(v, i) {
    // We need exact match of the word that is why === 
    if (input.find(w => w === v)) { // If word matches
      // Add new value
      res[i] = `<span class="${color}"> ${v} </span>`;
    }
  });
  return res;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------
// getChar
function getChar(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) { // Works on space
    let div = document.querySelector('#text');
    let res = [];
    if (checkSpelling(allWords, arr, e.target)) {
      // Change text color
      res = changeTextColor(arr, e.target, 'greenText')
      e.target.value = ''; // Empty input
      // Change div
      div.innerHTML = res.join(' ')
    }
  }
  if (e.keyCode !== 8) // Space removing only when is not Backspace
    e.target.value = e.target.value.trim();
}
```

```css
#text {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.red {
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.greenText {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  /** text-decoration: underline; **/
}
```

```html
<div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium alias aperiam commodi consequatur corporis cum dolores eaque in labore molestias nam odio optio quas, quis voluptates! Architecto fuga impedit voluptatum.</div>
<hr>
<input type="text" id="text_input" onkeydown="getChar(event);">
```